# Flutter: firebase_admob vs admob_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-admob

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

What are the differences between these 2 packages?

`firebase_admob` is the official one while `admob_flutter` will support native ads soon (apparently). I have tried them both and found no issues but I wanted to know which one is better than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message that they will support native ads was listed since [Dec. 10 2018](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter/versions/0.1.0), the first version.

Also even though it is called `firebase_admob` and it may seem like it is directly constructed for Flutter if you look at the GitHub repo readme, it shows that it is part FlutterFire.

[firebase-admob] tag exists while [admob-flutter] on Stack Overflow which makes it seem like it would be harder to get help when using since both of the packages don't have a proper API doc

It seems like `firebase_admob` would be better than `admob_flutter` as it seems to have a bit more features and can be more trusted to be maintained and up to date.

Update Edit: Now [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) has been released with native ads for flutter.

Comment: Yeah, those were my thoughts. But in terms of functionality I guess both are the same? I mean, there is no performance difference or profit % taken? (I remember this last thing with one of the Cordova packages)

Comment: I highly doubt that there would be a large difference in performance as they both use admob. Firebase admob has the extra functionality of native ads.

Comment: The firebase_admob plugin will be deprecated in April 2021 in favor of Google Mobile Ads SDK for Flutter. https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

Comment: I don't know why they didn't mention this to avoid confusion since very first moment